# Running MacOS shortcuts shell command from node script

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, zsh

I am trying to run MacOS shortcuts via NodeJS script. To achieve that I created shortcuts in the MacOS Shortcuts app, which normally run in the terminal (ZSH) by typing `shortcuts run shortcutname` ([Docs](https://support.apple.com/en-en/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac)). They work fine when typing them directly into the terminal, but not when called from a NodeJS script.

My script looks like this:

```
exec('shortcuts run shortcutname', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

When starting the script from the terminal `node script.js` it does nothing. It does not return anything nor does it finish. I tried replacing the command `shortcuts run shortcutname` by other commands the system should know. For example `ls`, or `git`. They  all work. Also when I leave out the `shortcutname` in the end, it complains about the missing parameter.

I was suspecting missing access rights, but apparently NodeJS runs as my normal user. Running `whoami` in script context returns my user name.

`NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers node script.js` did not show anything unusual. I also tried using the full path of the binary. `which shortcuts` gave me `/usr/bin/shortcuts`. Which I used in my script `/usr/bin/shortcuts run shortcutname`.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Though I thought I tested it, I found the solution:
`execSync` instead of `exec` works

It’d be cool if someone could explain why `exec` wouldn’t work.

Cheers!